# SCP AWS EC2 Fails

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm aware that there are other questions concerning the command, but I believe my situation to be unique.

Running the command:

```
scp -i ~/Documents/awskeys.pem -r website ec2-user@ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:home/ec2-user
```

gives the following output:

> Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd

and nothing else. No copying was done either. I have tried permutations of flags and many other possible solutions but come up empty-handed, and this was the recommended solution in many other threads. Even Google has only one instance, unrelated to SCP, of the message I received.

Any thoughts on what the problem could be?

Comment: Another thing of note: cht.sh says that the files to be copied come first, yet it seems not to work here as a file not found error is only thrown if the missing file is listed second.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue in your path
`scp -i ~/Documents/awskeys.pem -r website ec2-user@ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/`
. Then Please check security group and make sure that 22 port is allowed. If still stuck then try rsync as alternative - 
`rsync -e "ssh -i ~/Documents/awskeys.pem" -r website ec2-user@ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/`